# web2py get row object from reqeust.vars

Tags: python, request, web2py

I have the folloowing code segment:

```
for row in rows:            
     FORM(INPUT(_type='submit',_value=row.Name),  _action=URL('Review',args=[course_id,year],vars=dict(row=row)), _method='post')
```

where row is a row object.
But if i do:

```
request.vars.row
```

from the called Review function
It is of type 'str' with some string like

```
    <Row :{'Atribute Name',......}>
```

How do i pass the row object to that function?

Passing as args causes the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an entire dictionary as the value of a single variable in the query string. Given that the `Row` object is the only item in the query string, just convert it to a dictionary and pass that as the query string:

```
URL(..., vars=row.as_dict())
```

Then in the `Review` function, you would access individual field values as `request.vars.field1`, etc.